# Asp.net 4.0 site fails because no handler mapped with Classic appPool

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

When I create a Asp.net app and flip the appPool to "ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" it fails with the following error:

HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

After some searching it seems to be the handler not mapping correctly for the Classic mode but I can't find out where or how to fix that.

I have the full .Net 4.0 install with VS2010 and the app works fine if I flip the appPool to Integrated.  Also, it's a Windows 7 machine (I'm having the same problem on a Vista box).  Thanks in advance.

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by calling aspnet_regiis.exe from the .net 4.0 directory.
Also you can run the following command to see the list of handlers that are configured for your server:

```
\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config -section:handlers | findstr v4.0 | findstr Isapi
```

You should see the asp.net page factory, something like (in a 64-bit machine you should see them twice):

```
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />

<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried aspnet_regiis.exe but it didn't help and I do have the two *aspx rows you pointed out when I run appcmd.  But I'm still getting the "The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler" error when I have the appPool on classic.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I figured it out.  The machine had the handlers setup correctly but the Default Web Site my app was under did not.  I'm not sure why it didn't propogate but to fix it I just had to open the Handler Mappings in the site and click "Revert To Inherited"

Comment: Thanks. Clicking "Revert To Inherited" saved me a day

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to edit the script map (double click on PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit in Handler Mappings), click Request Restrictions button, go to the Access tab, and change it from "script" to "none".

Comment: This worked for me.  I do not think it's related to the permissions though.  I set it back to "script" and it still worked.  I think reverted back to Inherited and it still worked.  It's almost as if making a change just refreshes the handler and allows it to start working for classic mode.  Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Install net framework 4.5 extension via server management(IIS Function install). You'll get things OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a contribution to this issue. I am not saying that this WILL work for you it just might help is all:

For me this had nothing to do with the “IsapiModule” even though the exact error message I got was "HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list".

My scenario is that I got that error after I set “Enable 32-bit Applications” to "true" in the Application pool advanced settings for my Dot.Net 4.0 Classic Application Pool.

So on a whim, I simply changed the Pipeline Mode to “Integrated” and now it works for me. Which is silly because when I had it set to "Integrated" initially it didn't work, which is why I was using "Classic."

I hope this helps.